# How can I insert into a specific location of a MultiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame that looks similar to the following in structure. However in
practice it might be much larger and the number of level 1 indexes, as well as the number of level 2 index (per level 1 index) will vary, so the solution shouldn't make assumptions about this:

```
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ("a", "s"),
    ("a", "u"),
    ("a", "v"),
    ("b", "s"),
    ("b", "u")])

result = pandas.DataFrame([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10]], index=index, columns=["x", "y"])
```

Which looks like this:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
b s   7   8
  u   9  10
```

Now let's say I want to create a "total" row for each of the "a" and "b" levels. So given the above as input I would want my code to produce something like this:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
  t   9  12
b s   7   8
  u   9  10
b t  16  18
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
# Calculate totals
for level, _ in result.groupby(level=0):

    # work out the global total for that desk:
    x_sum = result.loc[level]["x"].sum()
    y_sum = result.loc[level]["y"].sum()

    result = result.append(pandas.DataFrame([[x_sum, y_sum]], columns=result.columns, index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(level, "t")])))
```

But this results in the "total" columns being appended to the end:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
b s   7   8
  u   9  10
a t   9  12
b t  16  18
```

Sorting using `result.sort_index()` doesn't do what I want either:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  t   9  12
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
b s   7   8
  t  16  18
  u   9  10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really annoyning, but reason for `sorted Multiindex` is better performance. Also if not sorted `MultiIndex` is possible some [UnsortedIndexError](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex) if need select by `MultiIndex`.

But if really need change positions of labels is possible use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

```
df = result.groupby(level=0).sum()
df.index = [df.index, ['t'] * len(df.index)]
df1 = pd.concat([result, df]).sort_index().reindex(['s','u','t'], level=1)

df1 = pd.concat([result, df]).sort_index()
print (df1)
      x   y
a s   1   2
  t   4   6
  u   3   4
b s   5   6
  t  12  14
  u   7   8

df1 = df1.reindex(['s','u','t'], level=1)
print (df1)
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  t   4   6
b s   5   6
  u   7   8
  t  12  14
```

More dynamic solution:

```
print (result.index.get_level_values(1).unique().tolist())
['s', 'u']

df1 = df1.reindex(result.index.get_level_values(1).unique().tolist() + ['t'], level=1)
print (df1)
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  t   4   6
b s   5   6
  u   7   8
  t  12  14
```

---

Another solution with [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) in custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    x.loc[(x.name, 't'),:] = x.sum()
    return x   

df = result.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)
        x     y
a s   1.0   2.0
  u   3.0   4.0
  t   4.0   6.0
b s   5.0   6.0
  u   7.0   8.0
  t  12.0  14.0
```

Comment: How will this work if the number of level 2 indexes changes? I mentioned this in my question but realised that the example didn't really illustrate it, so I've adjusted the example code to have an extra level 1 entry ("v").

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to convert the the level to categorical type so that the MultiIndex will be `is_monotonic_increasing`. This preserves order and the performance of MultiIndex will be better since its sorted.

Input:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
b s   7   8
  u   9  10
a t   9  12
b t  16  18
```

Convert level to categorical to preserve order.

```py
result.index = result.index.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(result.index.levels[1], categories=['s', 'u', 'v', 't'], ordered=True), level=1)
result.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
      x   y
a s   1   2
  u   3   4
  v   5   6
  t   9  12
b s   7   8
  u   9  10
  t  16  18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result.reindex(pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
("a", "s"),
("a", "u"),
("a", "t"),
("b", "s"),
("b", "u"),
("b", "t")
]))
```

Gives me

```
        x   y
a   s   1   2
    u   3   4
    t   4   6
b   s   5   6
    u   7   8
    t   12  14
```

Comment: Thanks. This would probably work but I don't know what the actual structure is in my real code (ie I can't just write out all the index values). I've amended the question to try and make this clearer.